# Use of rtorrent variables

Tags: linux, rtorrent

I'm using rtorrent.rc template given [here](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/wiki/CONFIG-Template), especially the use of variables:

```
# Instance layout (base paths)
method.insert = cfg.basedir,    private|const|string, (cat,"/home/USERNAME/rtorrent/")
method.insert = cfg.watch,      private|const|string, (cat,(cfg.basedir),"watch/")
method.insert = cfg.logs,       private|const|string, (cat,(cfg.basedir),"log/")
method.insert = cfg.logfile,    private|const|string, (cat,(cfg.logs),"rtorrent-",(system.time),".log")
```

I would like then to use those variables to change the destination directory of the download depending on the watch directory.

Before using those variable I was doing something like that:

```
schedule = watch_directory_movie,10,10,"load.start=~/torrent/watch/linux1/*.torrent,d.directory.set=~/linux1"
schedule = watch_directory_anime,10,10,"load.start=~/torrent/watch/linux2/*.torrent,d.directory.set=~/linux2"
```

Every torrent file going to ~/torrent/watch/linux1 was downloaded in the ~/linux1 folder.

Now I would like to do something like that (that does not work):

```
schedule = watch_start_l1,1,10,"load.start=(cat,(cfg.watch),\"linux1/*.torrent\"),d.directory.set=(cat,(cfg.basedir),\"/linux1\")"
schedule = watch_start_l2,2,10,"load.start=(cat,(cfg.watch),\"linux2/*.torrent\"),d.directory.set=(cat,(cfg.basedir),\"/linux2\")"
```

I don't want anymore hardcoded path in my schedule command, I want to use variables.
I do not succeed to find the correct syntax to use those variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
schedule = watch_start,121,10,((load.start,(cat,(cfg.watch),"start/*.torrent")))
schedule = watch_load,122,10,((load.normal,(cat,(cfg.watch),"load/*.torrent")))
```

See [here](https://github.com/pyroscope/pimp-my-box/blob/master/roles/rtorrent-ps/templates/rtorrent/_rtlocal.rc#L8-L11) for more.